# Is up to 95% of the human population genetically safe from leprosy?

Tags: medical-science, healthcare, public-health

In the article [How Armadillos Can Spread Leprosy](http://www.smithsonianmag.com/smart-news/how-armadillos-can-spread-leprosy-180954440/?no-ist) at the Smithsonian.com they state that

> "Even more reassuring: up to 95 percent of the population is
> genetically unsusceptible to contracting it."

Is this true? From my understanding, as well as a brief overview from Wikipedia, it just seems leprosy is harder to contract then people typically believe, but i cant find anything to source this 95% genetically unsusceptible claim.

Comment: "Up to 95%" means some percentage from 0 to 95.

Comment: @DJClayworth yes, but you can see they are stressing the point that people are genetically immune, which i haven't seen elsewhere.

Comment: The link they gave as a reference for the 95% doesn't even mention the number 95 or %. http://io9.com/5976108/armadillos-leprosy-and-you

Comment: @Tim exactly! lol

Comment: I found the 5% of non immune population in a [french medical publication](http://ipubli-inserm.inist.fr/bitstream/handle/10608/5276/MS_2004_8-9_729.pdf) page 730 *ref[1]* that refers for that figure to a 1999 [Lancet article by Jacobson RR, Krahenbuhl JL](http://www.thelancet.com/pdfs/journals/lancet/PIIS0140-6736%2898%2906322-3.pdf) about leprosy. I couldn't check the full text of the Lancet article to answer to your question.

Comment: @Graffito please don't attempt answers in comments.

Comment: @Sklivvz - I couldn't answer to the question, because I am not able to get access to the potential original source, i.e. the Lancet article.

Comment: I'm at a major university and I can't read the Lancet article either. They must be extremely expensive to subscribe to.

Comment: The lancet article does not give a percentage, only talking about  an overwhelming    majority "The    overwhelming    majority    of    people    are    not
susceptible  to  leprosy  and  after  typical  exposure  will  not
develop  it."